# How can i remove the GET parameters from url in django

Tags: python, django

I have the form which i am showing by normal view. Then i am send the GET parameters to djnago `ChangeList` view like django does for lookups like this

`student/?region__id__exact=1&status__exact=Published`

now is there any way to remove that from the URL in the address bar.

I don't users to see what i am doing

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of GET is that they are retrieved from the URL itself, removing them from the URL removes them entirely.

If you want them 'hidden' you will need to use POST.

Comment: Not strictly true as you can pass request headers via AJAX.

Comment: I am using django `CHnageList` view which only works like i have stated above in `lookup fields`

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP GET method of form submission passes the information from template to views through URL. If you want to "hide" information from URL use `POST` instead. In your form do like this:

```
<form action="/view_name/" method="post">
```

and in `views`:

```
request.POST['name']
```